# Activity not getting called via AlarmManager.

Tags: android

This is my code that I use  to call the activity HomeActivity. But, the call isn't going even though I've set it to 1 minute.

```
   protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();

            int minutes = 1;
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent i = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
            am.cancel(pi);

            if (minutes > 0) { 
                am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + mi

    > Blockquote

    nutes*60, minutes, pi); }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you are trying to start an activity via `AlarmManager`, you need to use `getActivity()`, not `getService()`, to create the `PendingIntent`.

Second, the periods for `AlarmManager` are in milliseconds, not seconds.

Third, `setInexactRepeating()` is designed for one of the pre-defined periods on AlarmManager (e.g., `INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES`).

Answer (score 0):

i guess repeat interval should be in milli seconds

and are you expecting

Intent i = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class); to start your activity?

just try normall and see if it would launch ur activity